# How to get cookie in filter rest api jersey

Tags: java, rest, cookies, filter, jersey

I am sending cookie from a client in Rest API request and I want to read on a filter. I am using this code on the filter for retrieving the cookies.

```
Map<String, Cookie> cookies  = requestContext.getCookies();
Cookie cookie = cookies.get("token");
String token = cookie.getValue();
```

But it returns null. Can anyone suggest me how can I retrive cookie on filter.

Comment: Have you tried to iterate over your cookies' map to see its contents?

Comment: @aribeiro i have also tried with iterate                                                                           Iterator it = requestContext.getCookies().entrySet().iterator(); but it gives me empty iterator . On resource i get cookies using cookieparam , But i am not getting cookies on filter.

Comment: What's the type of your `requestContext` variable?

Comment: ContainerRequestContext

Comment: Try do the following: `for (Cookie c : requestContext.getCookies().values()) if (cookie.getName().equals("token")) cookie = c;`

Comment: @aribeiro thanks it is works now for me

Comment: If it's ok with you, I'll place it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to retrieve your cookie, you should do the following:

```
for (Cookie c : requestContext.getCookies().values()) 
{
    if (c.getName().equals("token")) {
        cookie = c;
        break;
    }
}
```

Honestly, I don't know why you could not retrieve your cookie by its key, since the `ContainerRequestContext` [documentation](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getCookies()) states that `getCookies` returns
a read-only map of **cookie name** (String) to Cookie.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyArtist had a suggestion so I suggested an edit for it on their behalf, as they don't have enough rep to do so.